# Using Prometheus to monitor multiple instances of Windows desktop applications

Tags: c#, .net, prometheus

We plan to use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) to collect metrics about complex .NET desktop application. However, the usual approach with the `MetricServer` which allocates some pre-defined port to expose the metrics for scraping does not work as there may be multiple instances of the desktop application process run by same or different users on the same host machine at the same time.

This is typical problem with Prometheus when you have to instrument and collect metrics from multiple instances of the same process running on the same machine.
I am not sure what is the best way forward here, use something like [Prometheus Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) Or is there another better approach?

Comment: It's the Prometheus way as far as I'm aware. You either have your ephemeral clients push their metrics onto a gateway that then gets pulled from or you can explore a pull-oriented system like Influx

Comment: You could pipe your metrics from each desktop application to a single service that runs the metric server or like @timur said, just use the push gateway.